# Userform Alt+tab in VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

How can I activate the <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>? 
When my userform is open, I can't <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd> with other files *(documents/internet/etc)*. Is there any code to this or configuration?

Comment: *Not other files. Just in other excel files

Answer (score 0):

On the userform properties, there is an option called "ShowModal". If you set it with the value "False", then you can use other UserForms or WorkBooks.

Just be careful, if you didn't index the WorkBook and WorkSheet that you are working on (in the Userform), the events on the Userform can misunderstand your code.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "misunderstand your code" please?

Comment: For exemple, supose you have a workbook called Felipe.xlsm, and you are using userforms on this Workbook. And on the Userform, you will get an information on the cell "A1", which is a number. Therefore, you can use the code:

Label1.Caption = Range("A1")

Ok?

On this code, the userform will get the information inside the Workbook that is active. Thus, if you let ShowModal as False, and start using another file called "Edd.xlsm". And the information inside the cell "A1" is your own name. If you let this Workbook active, the userform will get the information of this Workbook!

Comment: So, try always use the complete address of the information you want to get, like:

Label1.Caption = workbooks("Felipe.xlsm").Sheets("Plan 1").Range("A1")

This way, the code wont get from another Workbooks, but only on the one that you specified.